# Bing v7 to v8 Migration iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, bing-maps, bing-api

I'm having trouble on how to start migrating from V7 Bing API to V8, is there any guide for it?? I'm developing iOS app (Objective C) that's using Bing's V7 API. I have no idea how does this work, the developer from the project left without any note regarding this, and I cannot understand how did he use it since i'm a newbie. Are there anything that I need to understand first how to do this?

also does v8 already has/support objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps V7 and V8 are JavaScript based API's and do not use Objective C. It is highly likely that your app is hosting an HTML page that uses the Bing Maps V7 control inside of a WebView. This is how Bing Maps is integrated into most iOS and Android apps. Information on how to migrate the JavaScript API can be found here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx

Comment: Can't seem to find any hosting that's happening in the project. Can I know what is the easiest way to transition to V8? I can't see the starting point, but I know they are using Bing V7 because the logo in the map is still the old one

Comment: The logo likely isn't enough to know it is V7. There was a really old iOS control that a very small number of companies used. It is possible that is what your application is using. The API was retired a while ago and I don't think there is any documentation for it online. Migration requires a complete code rewrite of the map functionality. You will want to host an HTML page inside a webview, similar to using Apache Cordova.